# How do you remove the border from a QPushButton?

Tags: qt

I have some QPushButtons in the rows of a QTreeView, and they're showing up with these black borders around them that I can't seem to modify.  Currently I can grey out the buttons with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < QPalette::NColorRoles; i++){
    QPalette::ColorRole thisRole = static_cast<QPalette::ColorRole>(i);
    QColor newColor = commitPalette.color(QPalette::Disabled,thisRole);
    int grayColor = qGray(newColor.rgb());
    newColor.setRgb(grayColor,grayColor,grayColor,50);
    commitPalette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, thisRole, newColor);
}
```

But it doesn't do anything to the border.  I'd prefer to avoid using stylesheets, as I like the automatic color generation provided by QPalette's constructor

[image: Example of borders]

Comment: Are the dark borders still there if you don't make any changes to the default style or palette?

Comment: Yes, it's the default coloring (I've messed around with it in designer).  The only thing that seems to change it is by attaching a stylesheet, but then you lose the nice look of the bevel.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using Qt creator, right click the QPushButton and setStyleSheet as `border: none;` Thats it.

Comment: just what I was looking for! :-) minor amendment: in QtCreator 2.4.1 on Mac OSX Lion, the context menu option is called 'Change styleSheet...'; then add 'border: none;' in the text window in the dialog that opens - and the border is gone :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you set the QButton property isFlat = true it *should* disable the border unless it's being clicked.

Comment: unfortunately it also disables everything but the label.

Comment: Ah, well there's two options, one is to use a stylesheet, the other is to subclass the QButton and create it in your own specific style.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a stylesheet. From the code you can make it to a function:

```
void setFlatStyle(QPushButton *btn)
{
    btn->setStyleSheet(QString("QPushButton {border: 0px;}"));
}
```

Just pass the button in there and get your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { border: none; }")
```

As said @RajaRaviVarma